# How git deals with folder names with spaces

Tags: git

I have a folder by the name `31 Files of - oop`. When I try running this command:

> git rm -rf 31 Files of - oop

I get this fatal error :

> fatal: pathspec '31' did not match any files

How do I need to prepare the folder names with spaces for use in git?.

Comment: Try with `31\ Files\ of\ -\ oop`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try in this way :

`git rm -rf "31 Files of - oop"`  Where 31 Files of - oop is your file name.

Comment: Thsi removed the folder 31 Files of - oop. git rm -rf 31\ Files\ of\ -\ oop