# Git add a folder with spaces in the name

Tags: git, directory, addition, space

## Problem

When I want to add something to the staging area I normally type git add < folder-name >. However, I can't add folders with spaces in the name. My `git add` auto complete doesn't correctly escape the spaces.

### For example

I have a folder named: *Folder A*

I run the command `git add F < tab-autocomplete >` which becomes `git add Folder A/`. 
If I try and add this folder it will throw an error:

`fatal: pathspec 'Folder' did not match any files`

This is because the correct syntax should be `git add Folder\ A/`.

### Summary

I'm not sure how to fix this though and I can't find any resources with a permanent fix. This issue "[How git deals with folder names with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053304/how-git-deals-with-folder-names-with-spaces)" describes a fix. But it involves putting speech marks around the folder name which I don't really want to do. Is there a better solution?

I'm using git version 2.2.0 and zsh version 5.0.7. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the issue persists with the latest git 2.8.3?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the folder name inside ' and ' (single quotes).
In your example, try the following:

```
git add 'Folder A'
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: On windows, it must be double quotes, like git add "Folder A"

Comment: I mean, obviously "on Windows" is too broad. If you're using [MinGW-w64 with git-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43852861/1028230), the `'` is fine, for example. But it's a good point. ;^)

Comment: This works fine in Mac terminal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You check if the setup mentioned in "[git completion with zsh: filenames with spaces aren't being escaped properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132290/git-completion-with-zsh-filenames-with-spaces-arent-being-escaped-properly)" works:

> The shell backslash escapes the filenames as expected when I use tab completion to insert the file name.

```
% echo "testing" >> test<tab>
```

> autocompletes to this after hitting tab three times.

```
% echo "testing" >> test\ four\ -\ latest.txt
```

In other words, the proper completion shouldn't need quptes (`"`), but should escape spaces.

Comment: When I run the command

`echo "testing" >> test<tab>`

It will correctly auto complete. However, it doesn't autocomplete when I try `git add <tab>` as stated above. Could I clarify my question further?

As a work around I have started using `git add "<tab autocomplete>"` which escapes the spaces. But as you have said @VonC:

`proper completion shouldn't need quptes ("), but should escape spaces.`