# How do I return the git bash terminal to its former coloured state?

Tags: bash, git

I am on windows 10 and just had an issue with git bash.

When I was using git bash in the past month, it looked like the screenshot from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356595/why-is-mingw64-appearing-on-my-git-bash).

However, something happened in the last week or so and now it looks like the one from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/283236/cygwin-bash-prompt-is-wrapping-lines-on-the-same-line/767736) instead.

I looked through the answers of both of those, and more, but none of them told me how to return it.

I tried installing/updating git through their website but that didn't help.

Comment: Please paste the screenshot after running the command git -c color.ui=always status

Comment: Here is the console [screenshot](https://imgur.com/My2r4uL)

Comment: Look at the definition of your `PS1`, does it contain the color codes?

Comment: @WalterA what do you mean by PS1 here?

Comment: A prompt with colours is constructed with escape codes or `tput` commands in the definition of `PS1`. Do you have `export PS1=...` in your `.bashrc` ? What is the output of `echo "$PS1"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I first reinstalled Git completely from scratch. I realised that launching it in administrator made it work properly. Next, I launched bash and ran the following commands:

`cd ~
explorer .`

Which opened the login scripts directory. I deleted all the git created files in that directory, then restarted bash. This was the:
`.bash_history
.bash_logout
.bashrc
.gitconfig
.profile`

files.

Then, it started working again!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the below lines in your git config file and then restart the command prompt and run git commands.

```
[color]
branch = always
diff = always
interactive = always
status = always
ui = always
```

Comment: I added it using `git config -e` to get the right one, but it didn't impact anything.