# Where is the /usr folder in mintty (Git Bash for Windows)?

Tags: windows, git

New to git on Windows. After installing the latest version of git (from the [git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) website), you can type `cd /usr/bin` in standard Linux usage. But where exactly is this on my Windows file system? A search from the Windows command-line turned up two plausible locations. Which is the correct one and why are there two similar locations?

- C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
- C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have:

```
vonc@voncavn7 MINGW64 /usr
$ ls
bin  etc  lib  libexec  share  ssl
```

If I check usr:

```
D:\prgs\gits\current\usr>ls 
bin/  etc/  lib/  libexec/  share/  ssl/
```

And mingw64

```
D:\prgs\gits\current\mingw64>ls
bin/  doc/  etc/  lib/  libexec/  share/  ssl/
```

So it looks like it is `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.

As explained in "[Why is “MINGW64” appearing on my Git bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357153/6309)", The `MINGW64` is the value from the `MSYSTEM` environment variable.
It is part of [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), which consists of three relatively separate subsystems: msys2 , mingw32 and mingw64.

From "[Zsh on Windows via MSYS2](https://medium.com/@borekb/zsh-via-msys2-on-windows-3964a943b1ce)" from [Borek Bernard](https://twitter.com/borekb):

> - msys2 (sometimes called just msys) is an emulation layer — fully POSIX compatible but slow.
> - mingw subsystems provide native Windows binaries, with Linux calls rewritten at compile time to their Windows equivalents.
>     For example, [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is a [mingw64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) binary (unlike msys Git which utilizes the compatibility layer and is therefore slow).

See also "[How are msys, msys2, and msysgit related to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309)".

Comment: Yes, that looks right, but curious why the `mingw64` folder. What is it for?

Comment: @AlainD I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Awesome, that answers the question